# Convert list of dataframes to list of numeric vectors in R

Tags: r, list, vector, dataframe, numeric

I have a list `L` of dataframes. The elements (dataframes) of `L` are unnamed. Each element includes only one variable `Var` (same for all elements) and one observation (unique across elements). The observations are lists of random "numbers". An elements of `L` can look like: `:'data.frame': 1 obs. of 1 variable: $ Var: chr "\"4\", \"32\", \"25\", \"4\", "`. And `is.atomic(L[[1]]$Var)` returns `TRUE`. I am looking for a way to convert `L` into a list of unnamed numeric vectors. End result should be:

```
> L
[[1]]
[1]  4 32  25 4
```

Right now I have:

```
> L
[[1]]
                   Var
1 "4", "32", "25", "4",
```

I have tried `as.numeric` but keep getting the warning `NAs introduced by coercion` and the result is not as expected. Obviously I am doing something wrong. Any help is appreciated!

edit: deleted the `L` sample as it was unnecessary.

Comment: Can you share a sample of your list?

Comment: I edited the question. Hope that's how you meant!

Comment: An actual reproducable example would be better, as `lapply(L,function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x$Var)))`works for me, but the structure of `L` is probably not the same.

Comment: I see. I don't know how to do that unfortunately. All I know is that the elements of the list were originally `ngram` phrasetables. The characters have been replaced by "numbers" using `gsub` with `("`\\bA\\b`, 1, Var)` options. Don't know if that helps?

Comment: See @Andrew Gustars answer, something like that should work, as there seem to be some quotation marks in the mix. Or use `dput(L)` to get example data.

Comment: Hi @count, how would you modify your solution if you have multiple columns?

Comment: @amisos55 `lapply(L,function(x) {
  x[,ind] = apply(x[,ind],2,function(y) as.numeric(as.character(y)));
  return(x)
})` with ind being a vector of column indices you want to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your strings need separating and stripping of quotation marks, by the look of it. They might also be factors. Try something like this...

```
L <- list(data.frame(Var='"1","2","3","4"'),data.frame(Var='"3","4","5","6"'))

K <- lapply(L,function(df) as.numeric(gsub('"','',unlist(strsplit(as.character(df[1,1]),',')))))
```

Comment: This worked like a charm except that it introduced a fifth `NA` element in all of the vectors. Any idea why?

Comment: You last elemt is likely an `,` or empty string `""`, just remove that with `gsub`.

Comment: It looks as if you have a final comma at the end of each string.  If they are all the same length you could do something like `K <- lapply(L,function(df) as.numeric(gsub('"','',unlist(strsplit(as.character(df[1,1]),','))[1:4])))`

Comment: This should also work `lapply(L,function(x) gsub(",","",noquote(gsub('"',"",x$Var))))`